# Ruby on Rails using Symbols in calling methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to ruby on rails. And I got confused when using a symbol to reference a method in a controller.

[image]

Here, when calling the before_action method, we pass the set_event method as parameter, but we use a symbol on this.

But looking on the Event.new method, we pass the event_params method as parameter, but we are not using symbol.

Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first example, that's right. The `before_action` filter allows passing a method name as Symbol or String as its argument. But to create an instance of `Event` you need several different values, and for that, hashes are commonly used.

If you debug your code and check what `event_params` is, you're more likely to see it's an `ActionController::Parameter` object, which responds to a method `to_h` (and/or `to_unsafe_h`), and that's enough to create an instance of an ApplicationRecord inherited class.

So, for the first case you're invoking `before_action` with a Symbol, but in the second case `Event.new` is receiving the value `event_params` holds, which is a method accessible in your controller, but that evaluates to an `ActionController::Parameter` instance.

---

`:event_params` is a Symbol, because you constructed it that way by prefixing the identifier (name) with a `:`, in the other hand `event_params` should be a method and/or local variable, since it does not have any other way to identify as it's.

Depending on the value of `event_params`, they could be the same, for instance;

```
event_params = :event_params
# => :event_params
event_params == :event_params
# => true
```

In that sense, they do are the same because they point to the very same object;

```
event_params.object_id
# => 2155228
:event_params.object_id
# => 2155228
```

But what you need to understand is `:` makes a Hash (when valid) and `event_params` makes a local variable and/or method.

Comment: But what's the difference between :event_params and event_params? Doesn't they return the same thing?